# How to access 2nd tab on Google Sheets using App Script/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api, google-api-java-client

I want to access simply the 2nd tab to get email and name values to be used to send automated emails. Currently, the code is using the first tab. Additionally, how do I specify that it should take only rows (on the second tab) which have values instead of taking the entire column with many blanks which then throw errors?

```
function sendemail() {
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = spreadSheet.getDataRange();
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) { 
    (function(val) {
      var row = data[i];
      var emailAddress = row[1]; //position of email header — 1
      var message = 'Hi There!';
      var subject = 'Test';
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      })(i);
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you searched the documentation? `.getSheetByName()`? See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

Comment: @TheMaster I tried that one but it errors for me. var sheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('2ndtab');

Comment: Ask a new question for the error or edit your question to limit your question scope to the error. See [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the second sheet / tab in a [`Spreadsheet`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet) you can use the [`getSheets`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheets()) method and take the second element of the returned list of [`Sheets`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet):

```js
var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
var secondSheet = sheets[1];
```

To retrieve only populated rows use the [`getDataRange`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getDataRange()) method to retrieve the [`Range`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) in which data is present, and retrive the values.

```
var range = secondSheet.getDataRange();
var values = range.getValues();
```